# Transcribir consulta con eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent, php8

Tengo la siguiento consulta a la base de datos que me devuelve el resultado que quiero correctamente, lo que estoy intentando realizar ya que soy nuevo en laravel es transcribir esta consulta.

```
SELECT  T1.*, T2.*
    FROM boms T1
    LEFT JOIN listadofacturas T2
        ON  T1.partCode = T2.partCode
    WHERE   T2.partCode IS NULL and t1.id_boms=2

UNION 

SELECT  T1.*, T2.*
    FROM listadofacturas T2
    LEFT JOIN boms T1
        ON  T1.partCode = T2.partCode
    WHERE   T1.partCode IS NULL and t2.numeroFactura=123456566
```

y me gustaria llevarla a si mal no entiendo eloquent que tengo algo similar a esto y no me devuelve el mismo resultado

```
$primera= DB::table('boms')
        ->join('listadofacturas','boms.partCode','=','listadofacturas.partCode')
        ->whereNull('partCode')
        ->where('boms.id_boms','=',$boms)
        ->get()
$segunda= DB::table('listadofacturas')
        ->join('boms','listadofacturas.partCode','=','boms.partCode')
        ->whereNull('partCode')
        ->where('listadofactura.numeroFactura', '=', $factura)
        ->union($primera)
        ->get()
```

Espero que puedan ayudarme, desde ya muchas gracias

Comment: Buen día, eso que mostraste es `query builder` ¿Deseas utilizar eso o quieres hacerlo con `eloquent`?

Comment: puede ser que tenga un error de concepto, mi idea es realizar la consulta y que funcione, estoy aprendiendo a usar estas tecnologias. Asique mientras funcione porque estoy con el agua al cuello

Comment: Hay una [herramienta](https://jjlabajo.github.io/SQLtoEloquent/) que he utilizado un par de veces que trabaja bien dentro de lo que cabe para convertir consultas SQL a Eloquent, Query builder o "Raw" dependiendo de la complejidad de la consulta

Comment: Recomiendo siempre que el primer punto de partida sea la documentación: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#unions (*incluso trae ejemplos*)

Comment: No necesitas el union where admite multiples condicionales

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para lo que necesitas puedes usar el query builder de esta manera sin necesidad de eloquent:

```php
$primera = DB::table('boms as T1')
    ->selectRaw('T1.*')
    ->selectRaw('T2.*')
    ->leftJoin('listadofacturas as T2', 'T1.partCode', '=', 'T2.partCode')
    ->whereNull('T2.partCode')
    ->where('T1.id_boms', $boms);
$segunda = DB::table('listadofacturas as T2')
    ->selectRaw('T1.*')
    ->selectRaw('T2.*')
    ->leftJoin('boms as T1', 'T2.partCode', '=', 'T1.partCode')
    ->whereNull('T1.partCode')
    ->where('T2.numeroFactura', $factura);

$definitiva = $primera->union($segunda)->get();
```

Ya si necesitas que te devuelva valores relacionados a un modelo solo debes elegir qué modelo es el que necesitas (Bom o ListadoFactura) y quedaría algo como:

```php
Bom::selectRaw('boms.*')
    ->selectRaw('T2.*')
...
```

Comment: Listo, solucionado.